# "nodes near coords" shows y value instead of x

Tags: pgfplots

I am pretty new to LaTeX and have the following problem. From the `pgfplots` manual I found the example:

```
% Preamble: \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.5.1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Uses lowest $x$ coords for xmin,
        xbar,
        width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={\#participants},
        symbolic y coords={no,yes},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,no) (9,yes)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It should look like this:

[image: Good result]

instead it looks like this:

[image: Bad result]

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Please always add a full but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Here just add the minimal set of class, packages and the `document` environment. This way people can easily test your code and their solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example works fine for me, and produces

[image]

which is the desired result. Add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and compare it to

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pgfplots.sty    2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

It sounds like you need to update your distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\listfiles
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Uses lowest $x$ coords for xmin,
        xbar,
        width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={\#participants},
        symbolic y coords={no,yes},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,no) (9,yes)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```